# How to suppress deprecated ssl message output from mongo?

Tags: mongodb, bash

I'm trying to understand how I can disable mongodb warning messages about the deprecated usage of ssl.
I did add the --quiet flag in my connection string, but it doesn't seem to help.

Just for context - I'm writing a bash script that interacts with the database, perhaps there's a way to direct the output to a file or something?
A newbie here so please excuse me about it :)

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-12T10:58:02.347Z"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":12123,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Option: This name is deprecated. Please use the preferred name instead.","attr":{"deprecatedName":"ssl","preferredName":"tls"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-12T10:58:02.347Z"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":12123,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Option: This name is deprecated. Please use the preferred name instead.","attr":{"deprecatedName":"sslPEMKeyFile","preferredName":"tlsCertificateKeyFile"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-12T10:58:02.347Z"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":12123,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Option: This name is deprecated. Please use the preferred name instead.","attr":{"deprecatedName":"sslCAFile","preferredName":"tlsCAFile"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your bash, any command output can be filtered, modified, sent to a file, ...

Illustration:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Eliminate all output
/bin/ls -c1 /etc >/dev/null

# Filter the output, remove all files containing the word "host"
/bin/ls -c1 /etc | grep -v host

# Send to a file
/bin/ls -c1 /etc >output_file

# Send to a file and see the messages on your terminal
/bin/ls -c1 /etc | tee output_file

# Hide only the error messages
/bin/ls -c1 /etc 2>/dev/null

# Send all output AND errors to a file
/bin/ls -c1 /etc >output_file 2>output_file

# Same as above, other syntax
/bin/ls -c1 /etc >output_file 2>&1

# Modify the output.  Here if the filename contains "host", replace it  by "AAAA"
/bin/ls -c1 /etc | sed 's/host/AAAA/'
```

You can adapt any of these methods to your command output.

Comment: onceI start the script, I do not want to see these deprecated mongo messages in my console output (not writing to a file). I'm not sure i understand how to modify it within the script itself

Comment: At the end of your mongo command line, add `2>/dev/null`.  It will suppress all error messages (well those that are sent to stderr).  But keep in mind that suppressing them could cause problems later if another error occurs.